# How to convert text to columns and ignore some delimiters

Tags: excel

I've tried to copy/paste a price list from a PDF into an excel sheet, but everything pastes into a single column (A), rather than converting it to the appropriate number of columns.

Using text to columns with a space delimiter doesn't work because many of the products have multiple spaces in the product name.

I've got about 300 lines with varying lengths of item description. There should be 4 columns: Item number, description, qty and price. But all 4 columns may have varying numbers of delimiters and characters.

Example:

```
MGB123 Brand 20 Mil Business Card Magnet 500 .225
NNR1221 Brand 15 Mil Custom Shaped Marker and Clip 250 4.123
PQXRF123 Brand 10 Mil Pen 1000 .221
etc...
```

I've used:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("~~~~~",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","~~~~~",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))+1,LEN(A1))
```

to get the price separated, but how would I alter the formula to get the next to last column?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml

Answer (score 2):

You can use these 4 formulas to extract the item number, name, quantity and price.

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"& SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>", "//s[1]")

=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE, FILTERXML("<t><s>"& SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>", "//s[position()>1 and position()<last()-1]"))

=FILTERXML("<t><s>"& SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>", "//s[last()-1]")

=FILTERXML("<t><s>"& SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>", "//s[last()]")
```

If TEXTJOIN isn't available in your version of Excel you could try using CONCAT.

```
=CONCAT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>", "//s[position()>1 and position()<last()-1]")&" ")
```

Which, again depending on your version of Excel, might need to be entered as an array formula using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

If CONCAT is unavailable try this,

```
=MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,FIND(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>", "//s[last()-1]"),A1)-FIND(" ",A1)+2)
```

though I'm sure there's probably a better way.:)

Comment: Good answer, but worth noting that TEXTJOIN is a function introduced to Office 365 and Excel 2019. Formula #2 won't work in older versions.

Comment: I keep on forgetting that.:)

Comment: If TEXTJOIN is not available then CONCAT will not be available either.  They came out at the same time.

Comment: I actually meant to use CONCATENATE but when I was typing the formula the first thing that came up was CONCAT and for some reason I thought that was the correct function. I'll edit the post so that formula should work in earlier versions.

Comment: CONCATENATE will not work as it does not accept arrays as entry.

Answer (score 1):

Here are formulas that should work on earlier versions of Excel also:

```
Item Number: =LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2)-1)
Description: =MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1,FIND(CHAR(1), SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",CHAR(1),LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))-1))-FIND(" ",A2))
Qty:         =--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",REPT(" ",99)),99*2,99))
Price:       =--TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))
```

The double unary at the beginning of Qty and Price are to convert the string to a number.

[image]